Is $R/I\otimes _RB\cong B/IB$ even if $B$ is not unitary where $B$ is a right $R$-module and $I$ is a right ideal of $R$.
In the textbook Algebra by Hungerford, there is an exercise:
Let $I$ be a right ideal of a ring $R$ with identity and $B$ be an $R$-module. Then $R/I\otimes _RB\cong B/IB$ as abelian groups.
To show this, let $g:R/I\times B\rightarrow B/IB$ be the middle linear map $g(r+I,b)=rb+IB$ and $i:R/I\times B\rightarrow R/I\otimes _RB$ be the canonical middle linear map. Then there exists a group homomorphism $\overline{g}: R/I\otimes _RB\rightarrow B/IB$ such that $\overline{g}i=g$.
Define $h:B/IB\rightarrow R/I\otimes _RB$ by $h(b+IB)=(1+I)\otimes _Rb$. I showed easily that $h\overline{g}=1_{R/I\otimes _RB}$. But when I tried to show $\overline{g}h=1_{B/IB}$,I had the following $\overline{g}h(b+IB)=\overline{g}(1+I\otimes _Rb)=1b+IB=b+IB$ where the last equality doesn’t hold unless $B$ is unitary. How can I solve this problem?

Author implicitly assume $B$ is unitary, just like $B$ is left $R$-module. Interesting part in the proof, in my opinion, is showing maps $g$ and $h$ are well defined.
We first show $g:R/I\times B\to B/IB$ is well defined. Let $r_1+I=r_2+I$ where $r_1,r_2\in R$. Then $r_1-r_2\in I$. We need to show $g(r_1+I,b)=g(r_2+I,b)$. By definition of subgroup generated by subset of $B$,
$$IB=\{\sum_{i=1}^nr_ib_i\mid n\in \Bbb{N}, r_i\in I, b_i\in B\}.$$
Since $r_1-r_2\in I$, we have $r_1b-r_2b=(r_1-r_2)b\in IB$. That is $r_1b+IB=r_2b+IB$. Thus $g(r_1+I,b)=g(r_2+I,b)$.
We now show $h:B/IB\to R/I\otimes_R B$ is well defined. Let $b_1+IB=b_2+IB$ where $b_1,b_2\in B$. Then $b_1-b_2\in IB$. So $b_1-b_2=\sum_{i=1}^n r_ic_i$ where $r_i\in I$ and $c_i\in B$. We need to show $h(b_1+IB)=h(b_2+IB)$. By properties of tensor product,
$$\begin{align} (1_R+I)\otimes b_1 &= (1_R+I)\otimes (b_2+\sum_{i=1}^nr_ic_i) \\ &= (1_R+I)\otimes b_2 + \sum_{i=1}^n(1_R+I)\otimes r_ic_i \\ &= (1_R+I)\otimes b_2 + \sum_{i=1}^n(1_R+I)r_i\otimes c_i \\ &= (1_R+I)\otimes b_2 + \sum_{i=1}^n r_i+I\otimes c_i \\ &= (1_R+I)\otimes b_2 + \sum_{i=1}^n 0_{R/I}\otimes c_i \\ &= (1_R+I)\otimes b_2 +0_{R/I\otimes_R B} \\ &= (1_R+I)\otimes b_2.
\end{align}$$
Thus $h(b_1+IB)=h(b_2+IB)$.
